# TypeScript: can we disallow inferring of mixed types?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference, tsconfig, inferred-type

In TypeScript, type inferring is pretty useful when there's only one single obvious resulting inferred type.

But when it infers a variable to be of mixed types, this can lead to invisible unexpected allowed mixed typing, that the developer might not have intended (even though they created a bug themselves).

Here's a simple example:

```js
const showMyArrayBoolean = someBooleanValue && someArray.length;
```

- Typescript infers `showMyArrayBoolean` to have the type of: `false|number`
- ...when the developer may have (incorrectly) expected it to simply always be a boolean

In this example, the developer made the mistake of assuming that `&&` will always result in a boolean, whereas in reality it doesn't.  So it can result in unexpected bugs that can only be found at runtime.  But it seems like something that some people might prefer the compiler to warn them about.

Is there some feature or `tsconfig.json` setting which can prevent TypeScript from inferring mixed types?

There's this `&&` case specifically which would be good to handle, but I'm mostly more interested in a broader solution that just disallows them entirely, regardless of cause.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But still, if there is such feature, what behavior do you expect instead? Say your example, what type do you think should TS infers instead.

Comment: @hackape in the case of inferring a mixed type, I would want such a theoretical setting (when enabled) to treat that as a warning/error.  So it would basically force you to specifically mark the type(s) you expect manually (which might in turn actually be a mixed type, if that's what you wanted anyway).

Comment: From my experience with TS, your proposal sounds to me bring more trouble than gain. I'll have to manually confirm to TS engine that, "yeah, I want union type ("mixed type" in your term) here, take it easy", every time it sees one. I personally would never want such behavior, it makes no sense. Union types comes up everywhere in my daily usage.

Comment: Fair enough.  These things are personal preferences.  I'm really talking about 100% inferred union types here, i.e. where there is zero marking of the type anywhere at all.  For any functions (or anything else) that have marked union types at the source of the value, this wouldn't be a problem... cause they're not *completely* inferred to begin with, so it's not really "every time it sees one".

Comment: So there's still plenty of room for union types everywhere through-out your code + libraries, it's only these rare occasions where they're 100% unmarked and inferred, which in my experience isn't actually that common.  If you're writing lots of code with *completely inferred* union types to begin with, then you're probably not really making much use of typescript anyway, and unlikely interested in such a setting like this.  And like most of typescript's features, it would obviously be optional.  I'm guessing it doesn't exist, but somebody might have some suggestions related to the subject.

Comment: Maybe the TS github issue page is a better place for this kind of discussion. You may try fire a feature request there and see people's reaction.